# Why is my vuejs dependency maz-ui maz-phone-number-input not formatted properly?

Tags: css, vue.js, input, dependencies

I am using the https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui/ library to include a country code dropdown in the phone number input field of my sign up form. Here is documentation for this particular component from the library.
https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui/documentation/maz-phone-number-input/

Why is my phone number field formatted like this?

[image]

rather than the expected appearance from the Maz-ui docs? ...

[image]

Here the relevant code in my component...

```
<template>
 <div>
   <MazPhoneNumberInput
     v-model="phoneNumber"
   />
   ... more code that is not directly relevant to this question.
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import { MazPhoneNumberInput } from 'maz-ui'
 import 'maz-ui/lib/css/maz-phone-number-input.css'
 export default {
  name: 'CuiRegister',
  components: { MazPhoneNumberInput },
 }
 ... code for handling the form submission that is not directly related to this question
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because it is not importing the css properly.

So if you import the component and its CSS properly it should work:

```
import MazPhoneNumberInput from "maz-ui/lib/maz-phone-number-input";
import "maz-ui/lib/css/base.css";
import "maz-ui/lib/css/maz-phone-number-input.css";
```

Or
add this code to your `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'component',
      {
        libraryName: 'maz-ui',
        styleLibraryName: 'css'
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

I got the second solution from the documentation [here](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui/documentation/get-started/)